# Min/max probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution

I am having a very hard time understanding probability problems involving max and min distributions, for example:

For $n$ i.i.d. exponential random variables, find $\Bbb P(X_1=\text{min}(X_1,...,X_n))$.

Can someone explain to me what exactly $\text{min}(X_1,...,X_n)$ refers to? All I can think is the probability that $X_1$ equals the smallest $X_i$, but if they are all identical they are all the same size. Please help!

Comment: Please search online the keywords "order statistics".

Comment: $X_i$ are not identical, but identically *distributed*. So smallest $X_i$ is meaningful.

Comment: I wouldn't be asking if I was understanding it from online explanations

Comment: @PkT can you expand on that? How exactly are identical distributions different from one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this example helps. Let's say you use two identical alarm clocks to set an alarm to wake you up. Each alarm goes off at a random time which follows the same probability distribution. Let's call these times for the first and the second clock $X_1$ and $X_2$. Now $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d., and $\mathbb P(X_1 = \min (X_1, X_2))$ is equivalent to asking "What is the probability that the first clock wakes you up?"

The answer is, of course, $0.5$. This is because the two clocks are exactly the same, so each has an equal chance of going off first. Similarly, in the case of $n$ variables, the answer is $\frac 1 n$.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you